# Truffle Install // npm WARN and Vulnerabilities -- How i solve that issues?

Tags: solidity, truffle, npm, visual-studio-code

I want to start working with Solidity in my Visual Studio Code so i installed Visuall Studio Code first, then nodejs and npm and in the end i try to install Truffles.

-I work on **Window 10 OS**

-**Nodejs** Version is **v14.16.0**

-**npm** Version is **7.6.3**

I tried to **install Truffle in my Windows PowerShell** with the command `npm install -g truffle`

and it had that problems
[image: Problems]

Then i run `npm audit fix`

and showed this

[image]

How can i fix that issues?

Thanks in advance!

***Update 1***

Finally i run the command `npm i --package-lock-only`

and it showed me 0 vulnerabilities

but then i run `truffle version` and it showed me this

[image]

How i solve that?

Comment: I have the same problem now. Do you arrive to solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I was learning coding smart contracts. The issue happened for me when I uninstalled truffle and installed it again to get an upgraded version of solidity.  The terminal print out for me was as below

[image: The printout in terminal after running npm install -g truffle]

So I run simply npm audit fix --force

I didn't spend time investigating what this command did but I have 0 vulnerabilities now

Answer (score 0):

I think you disabled protection with that npm audit fix --force idk if that's good but for sure doesn't sound like it

Answer (score 0):

I changed my execution policy.

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted